# Conjunction and preposition. Are these two sentences constructed correctly?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, conjunctions

> Developing countries are under high pressure in boosting local
>   economies to alleviate poverty, **whereas** having high risk in
>   deteriorating the environment to achieve such economic goals.
>
> Developing countries are under high pressure in boosting local
>   economies to alleviate poverty. **Also, in the meantime,** those countries have high risk in
>   deteriorating the environment to achieve such economic goals.

1. My understanding: 'whereas' is a conjunction, so it should be followed by either a full sentence or a noun. 'Also' is a preposition, so it should be inside of a full sentence. Am I right?
2. Do these two sentences read nature? if no, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentences are both problematic in several respects. Correcting bad grammar is not what we do on this site but here are some suggestions.

**Whereas** does not work in your example. **Whereas** balances or compares one thing against another. You will find numerous examples of its use online.

> Jane does not have the qualifications for this job whereas Margaret has both the qualifications and the necessary experience.

**Also** is not a preposition. Please see the source given below.

**Also, in the meantime** simply lengthens your text without adding anything.

I have never come across the verb **deteriorate** used transitively - with a direct object (as you use it) although I see that Merriam Webster allows this. I would use **damage** or **harm** instead.

I think that what you are trying to say is the following:

> Developing countries are under great pressure to boost local economies (in order) to alleviate poverty, economic goals that carry a high risk of damaging the environment.

https://www.wordsmyth.net/?ent=whereas

https://www.englishforums.com/English/PartOfSpeechAlso/gjck/post.htm